# Editing the name of a newly created tag

Tags: support, tag-wiki, tag-creation

I just [created a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/warhol). I am thinking that [warhol-effect](/questions/tagged/warhol-effect) would be a better title. Can I change this.

Please note, I am adding information to the tag, not creating an empty tag.

Comment: Retag, remove that one, and create a new tag with the desired name?

Comment: how do I delete that tag? I just created it

Comment: It will be automatically deleted at 03:00 UTC if there are no questions under it.

Comment: oh cool ty, do you want to make that an answer? Should I leave this question here, is it helpful??

Comment: You can change this, but it's better to put a little extra thought into it before creating a tag; if you create the `warhol` tag, then someone else uses the tag, and you then create the `warhol-effect` tag, now you have both tags floating around.

Comment: @lbt good point, will see if the tag endures.

Comment: Is this really a tag that we need? Do you anticipate more than 1 question being asked about the "Warhol effect"?

Comment: @CodyGray  the tag has been removed from the post, so it will be automatically deleted, pls see answer below ;) hahahhahaha

Comment: @CodyGray Err, go and check no it doesn't ;)))  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337110/jython-image-manipulation/17864427#17864427

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the newly created tag and add the desired tag to your question. At 3:00 UTC, the old tag will be deleted if no one else is using it.